# captured variables in a parallel.foreach loop

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

does each thread get its own copy that it can change? Do they all share the same one? Is it thread safe?

```
X var;
Parallel.Foreach(ls , it => Op(var, It));
```

Op does something to var. I assume that if var is a reference (say a `List<string>`) then there is one that all threads share and its my job to practice safe updating. What if X is int say?

What if var is `List<string>` but is null? If a thread creates a new List and writes it to var? Do the other threads see the new value of var?

I have done some tests but I want to make sure that what I am seeing is real and not that I am writing bad tests.

The last case (null) it seems each thread ends up with its own `List<string>`

Edit: 
Seems like I need to differentiate

```
   X var;
    Parallel.Foreach(ls , it => Op(var, It));
```

and

```
   X var;
    Parallel.Foreach(ls , it => {
          ....
          var = <something>
          ....
      });
```

ie the lambda itself modifies the variable. In this case its shared. But in the function (Op) case the usual rules about pass by value apply

In the case where var is shared does the task parallel library manage concurrent access or do I have to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass `var` in `Op` by value, so `Op` can not change `var`, because `Op` have only copy of it.

**Edit:**

> ie the lambda itself modifies the variable. In this case its shared. But in the function (Op) case the usual rules about pass by value apply

Yes, if you want to share variable, then you should refer it by lambda itself or pass it in `Op` by reference (`Op(ref var,it)`, assuming that signature of `Op` also changed), not by value.

> In the case where var is shared does the task parallel library manage concurrent access or do I have to do it?

You have to manage concurrent access by yourself.

Comment: That's simply saying that his particular implementation happens to never mutate the variable, not that it couldn't.  The lambda (and as a consequence, the code accessed from each thread) is closing over the variable, meaning that each thread can mutate it and have those mutations observed by the others.

Comment: @Servy `Op` can not mutate variable, as it does not see variable, it only see value.

Comment: That's true, but the thread, namely the code run via the lambda, *does* see the variable and *can* mutate it.  Again, the fact that the particular implementation of the lambda shown *doesn't* mutate the variable, doesn't mean that it *couldn't*.

Comment: @Servy And I does not say "lambda can not change `var`", I say "`Op` can not change `var`"

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that, but the question *isn't* just asking about the implementation of `Op`.  It asks if all of the threads have access to the same variable, and whether mutations to it would be visible between them.  They all do share the same variable, and mutations to it *would* be visible between them.  That the implementation shown doesn't ever involve them mutating doesn't change that. You have provided factually correct information and yet *failed to answer the question*.  Your answer could also say that 1 + 1 = 2, and that would be correct, and yet still not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Only the variable reference is copied. Not the variable data. It is as if all of the local variables are passed to the anonymous delegate via the method call.

Per [MSDN (Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide))](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)

> A reference to the outer variable n is said to be captured when the
>   delegate is created. Unlike local variables, the lifetime of a
>   captured variable extends until the delegates that reference the
>   anonymous methods are eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: the reference isn't even copied; all invocations of the lambda will access the same *variable*.

Comment: The same object. In code the object is named by the variable. If the caller changes the properties of the object, the anonymous method will see those changes.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  It's also true that if one of the invocations mutates the *variable*, and not the value that it references (if it's even a reference type) then that change will also be observed by the other invocations, because they all share the same *variable*, rather than copying it.  Closures close over *variable*, not *values*.

Answer (score 0):

All of the invocations of that lambda will be accessing the same variable.  There will not be separate copies for each invocation.

Closures are going to be transformed by the compiler into something that is the morale equivalent of the following:

```
public class ClosureClass
{
    public X var;
    public void method1(Y it)
    {
        Op(var, it);
    }
}
```

---

```
IEnumerable<Y> ls = null;
ClosureClass closure = new ClosureClass();
closure.var = null;
Parallel.ForEach(ls, closure.method1);
```

A class will be created to represent the closure, one instance will be created ate the start of the method, the lambda's body will map to a method in the closure's class, and all usage of closed over variables will be fields in that class.  As you can see here, all of the invocations of `closure.method1` will end up accessing the same field of the same instance, which is a singular variable.

Comment: thus Op(null, it) is different from Op(var, it) with var = null? In the first case nothing is captured and each thread sees its own 'null' , in the second case they all share the same var

Comment: @pm100 Yes, if you don't close over the variable and instead inline a value, you won't have closure semantics.